# How do I align this menu in the middle (and still be responsive)?

Tags: html, css, web

Website page:
http://atlantiscorp.com.au/index.php/atlantis-solutions/landscaping-solutions/australian-vertical-gardens

I'm trying to align the menu below the big title in the middle. I can get it, somewhat, by setting the UL's width (to 600px) then doing a margin:0 auto, but this is not responsive and it's not truly centered in the middle either.

Any ideas ? :(

Comment: Please include code with your question... once your issue is resolved and you update the live page, the question will not be useful to others researching similar issues. _Questions concerning problems with code you’ve written must describe the specific problem and include code responsible for that problem._

Comment: Did you want it like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FDcwp)? I have used max-width: 600px; and margin: 0 auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try these style adjustments:**

```
ul.nav {
  /* width: 600px; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.nav li {
  /* float: left; */
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Unset the `width:600px;` (or set it explicitly to 100%) of `ul.nav` and also give it `text-align: center;` 
Remove the `float:left;` from `ul.nav li` and set `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment or to ask for more info on understanding, so i am giving my response here based on whatever i have understood.
As i don't have your code, My suggestion would be to use `position:absolute; left:200px(try changing`200px`to suit your positioning requirements)` on your sub text which contains about, benefits ...

Comment: this wouldn't be a responsive solution as the OP asks for.